# cors issue with google places api using angularjs(yeoman)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, xmlhttprequest, cors, google-places-api

I am trying to configure a Google Places API and display the search results using AngularJS. I've generated angular using yeoman and serving it using 'grunt'. I'm using it to find all the "sport" results around a certain location.

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
 .controller('httpReqController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope,$http) {
    console.log('next is on click');
    $scope.myFunction = function() {
      console.log('on click in place');
      $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+
                  $scope.address+
                  '&key=<API_KEY>')
        .success(function (response) {
          $scope.names = response;
          var location = response.results[0];
          console.log(location.geometry.location);
      // HTTP request to find the sport around the users place
      var comURL2 ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+
                   location.geometry.location.lat+
                   ','+
                   location.geometry.location.lng+
                   '&radius=50000&types='+
                   $scope.sport+
                   '&name='+
                   $scope.sport+
                   '&key=<API_KEY>';

      $http.get(comURL2).success(function (response) {
        $scope.names = response;
        console.log(response);
      });
    });
};
}]);
```

This gives me an error on the console

```
next is on click                                                  search.js:23
on click in place                                                 search.js:30 
Object {lat: 48.1603191, lng: 8.8528498}
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=48.16…types=badminton&name=badminton&key=<API_KEY>. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've already tried adding cors headers in gruntfile.js

```
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9000,
    // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  },
  livereload: {
    options: {
      open: true,
      middleware: function (connect) {
        return [
          connect.static('.tmp'),
          connect().use(
            '/bower_components',
            connect.static('./bower_components')
          ),
          connect().use(
            '/app/styles',
            connect.static('./app/styles')
          ),
          connect.static(appConfig.app)
          function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
            next();
          },
        ];
      }
    }
  },
```

But the error persists.

Any ideas where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you fix this? if not, are you using any httpInterceptors? can you post them if so? thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I discontinued working on this problem and don't have a proper solution. 
I used a Chrome App [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin-*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi/) which fixed the problem in development at the least.